# Assign event handler to ContextMenu item defined in custom style

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, datatemplate

I have created Context menu style with predefined MenuItems in it:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" x:Key="DataGridColumnFilterContextMenu">                
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#868686"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Background="#FAFAFA"> 
                                <Grid MaxHeight="500">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Filtrēt" StaysOpenOnClick="True" Name="DynSearch">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                                                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
                                                     Source="/Furniture;component/Resources/search4.png" />
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <Separator  Margin="20 5 20 0"  Height="2" Width="Auto" />
                                    <MenuItem Margin="5 5 0 0" StaysOpenOnClick="True" >
                                        <MenuItem.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate >
                                                <CheckBox Padding="15 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >Iezīmēt/Atzīmēt visus</CheckBox>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </MenuItem.Template>
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                                                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
                                                     Source="/Furniture;component/Resources/search4.png" />
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <Separator Margin="20 5 20 0" Height="2" Width="Auto" />
                                    <RadioButton Margin="5 5 0 0" Padding="15 0 0 0" GroupName="Sorting" Content="Augoša secībā" IsChecked="True"/>
                                    <RadioButton Margin="5 5 0 0" Padding="15 0 0 0" GroupName="Sorting" Content="Dilstoša secībā" />
                                    <Separator Margin="20 5 20 5" Height="2" Width="Auto" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
                                              Margin="1,0,1,0"                                            
                                              CanContentScroll="True"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>                              
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now I assigned style to new ContextMenu and wanted to assign Click event handler to MenuItem defined in style with header "Filtrēt". I tried do it like following:

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.Style = Application.Current.Resources["DataGridColumnFilterContextMenu"] as Style;
var controlList = ((((cm.Template.LoadContent() as Border).Child as Grid).Children)[0] as StackPanel).Children;
MenuItem filterItem = (controlList[0] as MenuItem);
filterItem.Click += MiFiltre_Click;
```

And when I clicked debugger It didn't come to MiFiltre_Click method. I tried different events like MouseDown and PreviewMouseDown. Also I tried to bound ICommand and this also didn't work.

Then I searched this question and realized that cm.Template.LoadContent() may actually create new instance of my ContextMenu template and I am trying to bound my event handler to different control instance. Then I tried to get ContextMenu node controls with VisualTreeHelper and LogicalTreeHelper and this also didn't work.

So here are questions:

1. How to achieve Click event handler binding?
2. If 1st question is too
   hard, then how to get ContextMenu childrens current instance defined
   in custom style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume this menu Style is defined in a resource dictionary named "MyResources.xaml".

1. Create a Class file in the same project folder, and call it "MyResources.xaml.cs".
2. Make it a partial class like this:

   ```
   namespace WhateverNamespace
   {
       public partial class MyResources
       {
           private void FilterMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)sender;

               //  Below, PlacementTarget is the control the user right-clicked on. 
               //  Use that directly if you want that instead of its viewmodel. 

               //  This works with the conventional ContextMenu defined below.
               //ViewModel viewModel = ((FrameworkElement)((ContextMenu)mi.Parent).PlacementTarget).DataContext as ViewModel;

               //  This works with your template design. The only difference is 
               //  TemplatedParent instead of Parent. 
               ViewModel viewModel = 
                   ((FrameworkElement)((ContextMenu)mi.TemplatedParent).PlacementTarget)
                   .DataContext as ViewModel;

               MessageBox.Show("FilterMenuItem_Click");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Give the resource dictionary an `x:Class` attribute:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary 
       x:Class="WhateverNamespace.MyResources"
   ```
4. Wire up the handler:

   ```
   <MenuItem 
       Click="FilterMenuItem_Click"
       Header="Filtrēt" 
       StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
       Name="DynSearch">
   ```

By the way, you don't need to mess with styles and templates to create a `ContextMenu` resource:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridColumnFilterContextMenu">
    <MenuItem 
        Click="FilterMenuItem_Click"
        Header="Filtrēt" 
        StaysOpenOnClick="True" 
        Name="DynSearch">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image
                RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
                Source="/Furniture;component/Resources/search4.png"
                />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <CheckBox>Iezīmēt/Atzīmēt visus</CheckBox>
        </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image   
                RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" 
                Source="/Furniture;component/Resources/search4.png"
                />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Sorting" Content="Augoša secībā" IsChecked="True"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Sorting" Content="Dilstoša secībā" IsChecked="True"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I can't do that because  I need use some variables in event handler from other class Instance. By the way I keep this style in App.xaml .

Comment: @Andrew_Miller See update for one way to get to the viewmodel in the Click handler. I've never seen a context menu implemented the way yours is, but I'm sure you could find a way.

Comment: @Andrew_Miller Whoops, it turned out to be quite easy. Updating again.

Comment: PlacementTarget was not UserControl but something like button where ContextMenu were asigned, but it is Ok I binded all I need to ContextMenu tag and it was most important to get to it in that handler. Thanks a lot,  Ed Plunkett! Now I can do what was intended.